# How to Append The Calculated Arithmetic to The List?

Tags: python, list, append

Let say we have this simple arithmetic:

```
y = 1 + 1
```

Can I append the result of the arithmetic to a list directly like so:

```
num_list = []
l = num_list.append(y)
```

I have tried to print the list to see if the result has been appended to the list, but I noticed it gives me "None" as output.  Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it! Can you be more explicit? @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not print `l`, you should print `num_list` to see the appended list. Here is the sample test in python command line

```
>>> y = 1 + 1
>>> list1 = []
>>> list1.append(y)
>>> print list1
[2]
>>> print l
None
>>>
```